# PCI passthrough KVM

Tags: linux, virtualization, pci-express, nvidia-graphics-card

I am trying to passthrough my Tesla K40m GPU accelerator to a `qemu-kvm` virtual machine via the VFIO driver on Ubuntu 14.04.2.

I downloaded all drivers and CUDA libraries, and I compiled all sample files successfully; however when I run them they do not finish.  For example, this is the run log of `deviceQuery`:

```
deviceQuery Starting... CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking) Detected 1 CUDA Capable device(s) Device 0: "Tesla K40m" //INFO ABOUT IT Compute Mode: < Default (multiple host threads can use ::cudaSetDevice() with device simultaneously) >

deviceQuery, CUDA Driver = CUDART, CUDA Driver Version = 7.0, CUDA Runtime Version = 7.0, NumDevs = 1, Device0 = Tesla K40m Result = PASS
```

Then it just hangs, leaving the only option to quit by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.  Moreover, I installed everything on the host too, and on the host, it finished sucessfully without any problems.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
dmesg on VM says only: [ 1475.225692] nvidia 0000:00:08.0: irq 51 for MSI/MSI-X dmesg on host: kernel: [ 2897.503162] vfio-pci 0000:02:00.0: irq 324 for MSI/MSI-X
```

Additionally, any call to PCI is taking too much time.  For example I tried to call `nvidia-smi` in the virtual machine (VM) and on the host system and traced it via `strace`. Here output from VM:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+ 
| NVIDIA-SMI 346.59 Driver Version: 346.59 | 
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU Name Persistence-M| Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0 Tesla K40m Off | 0000:00:06.0 Off | 0 |
| N/A 54C P0 64W / 235W | 55MiB / 11519MiB | 0% Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes: GPU Memory |
| GPU PID Type Process name Usage |
|=============================================================================|
| No running processes found |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
% time seconds usecs/call calls errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
98.67 4.688353 275785 17 open
1.08 0.051337 3020 17 close
0.23 0.010722 104 103 ioctl
0.01 0.000261 22 12 read
0.00 0.000235 9 26 mmap
0.00 0.000177 15 12 write
0.00 0.000127 16 8 munmap
0.00 0.000107 11 10 mprotect
0.00 0.000094 19 5 1 stat
0.00 0.000070 5 15 fstat
0.00 0.000055 8 7 7 access
0.00 0.000030 30 1 execve
0.00 0.000018 5 4 fcntl
0.00 0.000015 8 2 1 futex
0.00 0.000013 4 3 brk
0.00 0.000007 4 2 rt_sigaction
0.00 0.000006 6 1 getrlimit
0.00 0.000005 5 1 lseek
0.00 0.000004 4 1 set_robust_list
0.00 0.000003 3 1 rt_sigprocmask
0.00 0.000003 3 1 arch_prctl
0.00 0.000003 3 1 set_tid_address
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00 4.751645 250 9 total
```

Here is output when I run `nvidia-smi` on the host (I detached it from VM beforehand):

```
+------------------------------------------------------+ 
| NVIDIA-SMI 346.59 Driver Version: 346.59 | 
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU Name Persistence-M| Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0 Tesla K40m Off | 0000:02:00.0 Off | 0 |
| N/A 48C P0 64W / 235W | 55MiB / 11519MiB | 60% Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes: GPU Memory |
| GPU PID Type Process name Usage |
|=============================================================================|
| No running processes found |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
% time seconds usecs/call calls errors syscall
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
82.25 0.571723 33631 17 open
15.70 0.109104 6418 17 close
1.76 0.012264 119 103 ioctl
0.10 0.000664 44 15 read
0.05 0.000370 14 26 mmap
0.02 0.000155 16 10 mprotect
0.02 0.000152 22 7 7 access
0.02 0.000134 9 15 fstat
0.01 0.000100 13 8 munmap
0.01 0.000078 26 3 brk
0.01 0.000070 6 12 write
0.01 0.000069 17 4 fcntl
0.01 0.000062 62 1 execve
0.00 0.000029 6 5 1 stat
0.00 0.000021 11 2 rt_sigaction
0.00 0.000021 11 2 1 futex
0.00 0.000010 10 1 rt_sigprocmask
0.00 0.000010 10 1 getrlimit
0.00 0.000010 10 1 arch_prctl
0.00 0.000010 10 1 set_tid_address
0.00 0.000009 9 1 set_robust_list
0.00 0.000000 0 1 lseek
------ ----------- ----------- --------- --------- ----------------
100.00 0.695065 253 9 total
```

As you can see, "`open`" from VM takes too much time.  I have no idea why.

## Can anybody help me?  Sorry for so much text.

UPDATE 1:
Forgot to add that server is 
SuperServer 8047R, Motherboard:Super X9QRi-F+, RAM: 128GB

Comment: What's your motherboard/ram on the host?

Comment: Thanks for showing interest, I updated server info. If there are anything more you need to know - tell me.